# VFD Motor Bidirectional Control

Tags: control, vfd, bidirectional, latching-relay

So I have a control panel which controls the speed and direction of a motor in a sliding mechanism. the direction can be inverted using a tri-state selector on the panel. the selector input is a **COMMON** signal coming from the drive and the output is **P1** "direction 1" and **P2** "direction 2" which are going back to the drive. what I want to do is to add 2 limit switches on the mechanism and allow the drive to revert direction either by the selector or the limit switches. knowing that in order to the drive to be able to reverse the direction, the signal (P1 or P2) has to be continuously active high, So I will add a relay to achieve that with the limit switches "Latch Circuit". but the problem is how to link the selector and the limit switches without the need to add more components rather than the relay.

These are the available components that can be used:

[image]

Comment: I see you not thought about surge current or a proper Servo design. Imax = 2Vdd/DCR

Comment: @tonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The design aleary exists, I would like to add the feature of controlling the motor direction by the 2 limit switches. By the way its an AC geared motor connected to the VFD

Comment: Still not a great plan. It is better to compute stored mechanical then electrical energy and slow down early with extra sensing before end stop than reverse full power. End stop should stop before change power in the other direction,  then have near end stop and full crash prevention end stop.

Comment: For sure Sir, the VFD has a decelration function activated when limit switch is energized. Also the speed is too much low, in the range if 2 RPM or less. So there is still enough time for the mechanism to stop before something crashes.

Comment: ok then with control V/f ramps ok. But it must be one in logic not power. For power brakes only.

Comment: Yes proff, the aim of the latch circuit will be to control (control signals) that are going from and to  VFD.

Comment: In my XY gantry I only used SPST switches and internal pullup. I don’t know why you need SPDT and a relay.

Comment: The panel is of a classic control type, so all switches have NO NC terminals by default. So the first thing came to my mind is to treat it as a start stop latch circuit, thus this yields for adding only one component to the circuit "relay" and also maintain the ability to use both the rotary selector and the limit switch as requested by the customer.

Comment: If you want XOR each end stop ,  a boundless switch must clock a divide by 2 FF on each SPST end stop to toggle the polarity or a latching pulsed toggle Relay that I have not seen but is simple with TTL or CMOS Logic but is controlled by the VFD

Comment: Bounceless. ...typo

Comment: Cant be made with XOR logic because, there are two different outputs P1 & P2  for direction 1 & direction 2 respectively. The problem is with those two momentary limit switches, i want them to be synchronized with the selector output in order to continously supply the VFD with the required motor direction "P1 or P2"

Comment: If you say so. There are two ends and 2 directions and the controller only needs to know which one endstop was contacted unless you wish to have that redundant with a brake at endstop if it goes out of control. Then the controller logic can be modified to react accordingly. Do you really want 4 states of 2 switches to reverse logic of your controller or let the controller do this, just let me know if it went into the end zone. ie. why outsource your memory bits?

Comment: You could implement this but I would never. Only static endzone switches. For steppers the end crash could as little as a few steps beyond contact closure, but I don’t know your case. In my case my velocity was up to 1m/s over 1.1m XY span with a,v and position control in the CNC shield with EEPROM values for max acceleration and velocity on steppers. Very fast smooth and safe.

Comment: in my case I had a macro GCode file to accelerate and slow down at >1m to verify all 4 end stops wer working then use one corner as home. So the accuracy of my home switch was your end stop. For me mechanical was adequate, but if I needed better accuracy, I would choose optical and verify the aging of the position error.

Comment: I got the idea of what you are talking about. But my case is much easy than a CNC machine, its just a  mechanism that moves on one axis in both directions, also the speed is too much low. The mechanism is controlled by an operator via the selector to reverse the direction and a potentiometer to vary the speed as required. What i want to do is to add two limit switches at each path end  so that it can be operated automatically after setting the path according to the location of each limit switch "determining the path".

Comment: Oh then all you need is two SPDT push push switches at each end. 3 wire and also called 3 way switches or use vu2nan’s

Comment: Yes @Tony but Vu2nan answer will not work because signals are instantaneous. And this is why i would like to use a relay for latching

Comment: Using 16V inverters at 5V for low drive current when shorted to 0 or 5V but switches must be gold plated <2A type. With series R and cap to prevent inductive overshoot depending on wire length 10nH/CM

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to meet the requirement.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have not considered one of the main requirements, which is the signal must be continously active high in oreder to the VFD to rotate the motor in either direction. And that's why I'm using a latching relay.

Comment: Hello @vu2nan, Yes it's a latching type circuit. No worries 

Comment: Hi Ahmed, 'Motor On' is a motor start/stop holding relay. I am sorry I have missed  mentioning that. Will amend the schematic accordingly. P.S. I have reposted my earlier comment, with changes, as I could not edit it. I have also amended the schematic.

Comment: Then add back back inverters  to make it latch.

Comment: Hi Tony, That's just an electromagnetic relay, with its own holding contact, not shown in the schematic.